# Life choices how to know if one made the good choice

Tags: commentaries, free-will-bechira, parashat-nitzavim

G-d Himself tells us to choose between life and good, and death and evil. Sometimes good is translated as prosperity here and evil as destruction or adversity.

הַֽחַיִּ֖ים וְאֶת־הַטּ֑וֹב וְאֶת־הַמָּ֖וֶת וְאֶת־הָרָֽע

He also tells us to choose life.

In life one has to make big choices which could define one’s life like which place or home to live in should I become a lawyer or a doctor (a job to choose), and maybe even more important one has to choose a fitting spouse.

What does the Tenach teach us regards such choices, how do I make these and how do I know if I made a good choice or not. I want to choose life, so how does one choses life regards these matters?

Comment: The next verses state that choosing good/life means choosing to worship Hashem - so whatever you do in life should revolve that mission. On the specifics, best to seek advice from friends, relatives, rabbis, etc. And, of course, pray to Hashem for hatzlacha.

Comment: How to make the choices, and how to know if you made the right choice, are two separate questions. You should clarify your question to focus on one of them.

Comment: Deep down inside you will know about right and wrong choices.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of each day, make a cheshbon hanefesh (an accounting of the soul). Go through the day, looking at the decisions and emotional responses you had that day. Look at which middos (emotional capacities) tended to get triggered. Were the decisions from a place of anavah -- an honest assessment of self-worth, without needing to make the story about me? Did they evoke yir'as Hashem -- fear / awe / reverence of G-d? Ahavas Hashem -- love of Him? Or was I spending the day chasing ta'avah -- physical desires or kavod -- getting myself a little honor?

Preferably do this in writing. If you do write things down, you need an accommodation for Friday (or erev Yom Tov). If you get out of work early enough, perhaps do it before Shabbos, and then Saturday's record include all of Shabbos including Friday night, as well as Saturday evening.

When you see your decisions tend to come from the right place -- great! And when not, you now know what aspects need work. Also, great!

See Mesilat Yesharim's discussion of [Zehirut -- Awareness, ch. 2-5](https://www.sefaria.org/Messilat_Yesharim.2?lang=bi). The particular tool of keeping a Cheshbon haNefesh in chapter 3 (this [Sefaria link](https://www.sefaria.org/Messilat_Yesharim.3.12?lang=bi) will take you right there).

Rabbi Mendel Leffin (Reb Mendel Satanover) also wrote a book Cheshbon haNefesh, in which he adapts a shorthand form of this kind of journaling from Benjamin Franklin's autobiography. It doesn't replace the process I described above, but does give an option that requires less writing and still gets most of the same effect. (Nor could I find an on-line copy.)

But earlier than either is [Sha'ar Cheshbon haNefesh](https://www.sefaria.org/Duties_of_the_Heart%2C_Eighth_Treatise_on_Examining_the_Soul%2C_Introduction?lang=bi) in Chovos haLvavos (R' Bachya ibn Pequda 11cent, written in Judeo-Arabic.

Comment: I like the answer, but it doesn't really answer the question which asked what the Tanach teaches us about making life choices.

Comment: @simyou: You really asked three different questions (numbering inserted): "[1] What does the Tenach teach us regards such choices, [2] how do I make these and [3] how do I know if I made a good choice or not." I only answered the last one, because you made it the subject line and therefore I thought it was the core question.

Comment: @simyou: Tanakh's teachings on how to make right choices are buried in stories of people making the right or wrong ones and how it played out, and in the parables of Mishlei. Nothing that would neatly fit in a StackExchange answer.